# how i can resolve error of paddedsize in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Undefined function or method 'paddedsize' for input arguments of type 'double' 
how i can resolve this.

```
f = imread('cameraman.tif');
PQ=paddedsize(size(f));
F=fft2(f,PQ(1),PQ(2));
sig=40;
H=lpfilter('ideal',PQ(1),PQ(2),sig);
imshow(fftshift(H),[ ]);
G=H.*F;
g=real(ifft2(G));
g=g(1:size(f,1),1:size(f,2));
figure;
imshow(g,[ ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`paddedsize` is not a MATLAB builtin or library function. Presumably this comes from some third-party library you should try and find.

Answer (score 0):

'paddedsize' is a function available on the Matlab File Exchange [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32384-midas-2010/content/MIDAS_2010/paddedsize.m). In order to use the function you will need to download the m-file into your working directory or add the file location to your path.